# generate:doctrine:entity cause exception SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'symfony' inconnue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm beginner in Symfony. I follow Book step by step and in excercise about DoctrineFixturesBundle I got this problem.

Steps in this excerise include:

1. Prepare distribution of Symfony-with-DoctrineFixtureBundle
2. Open new project
3. Generate bundle
4. Generate access class (php app/console generate:doctrine:entity)

and so on. I stuck on point 4. Command generate:doctrine:entity causes three messages and did't create any entity in my project.

three messages

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'symfony' incon
  nue

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'symfony' inconnue

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'symfony' inconnue
```

all what i did in console is below:

```
C:\wamp\www\17CHUJNIA>php app/console generate:bundle


  Welcome to the Symfony2 bundle generator
     .    
     .
     .
  Bundle name [MyTestBundle]:
     .    
     .
     .
  Bundle generation


Generating the bundle code: OK
Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: OK
Confirm automatic update of your Kernel [yes]?
Enabling the bundle inside the Kernel: OK
Confirm automatic update of the Routing [yes]?
Importing the bundle routing resource: OK

  You can now start using the generated code!



C:\wamp\www\17CHUJNIA>php app/console generate:doctrine:entity


  Welcome to the Doctrine2 entity generator



The Entity shortcut name: MyTestBundle:Name

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'symfony' incon
  nue

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'symfony' inconnue

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'symfony' inconnue

doctrine:generate:entity [--entity="..."] [--fields="..."] [--format="..."] [--with-repository]

C:\wamp\www\17CHUJNIA>
```

Comment: check if the PDO driver is installed & enabled

Comment: extension named php_pdo_msql is marked as active.`;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an existing database and a valid connection to use this command line.
Check your `/app/config/parameters.yml` file and create your database before using commands line dealing with databases and entities.

Comment: it,s weird, becouse in the book step  titled "determine the parameters of the database connection (app/config/parameters.ini )" is no 5, scarcely after step no 4 ( generate:doctrine:entity)

Comment: `parameters.ini` ? Which book are you talking about? Maybe, it is outdated... I just trying with a valid database connection and it's works.

Comment: damn, it is outdated cause its using symfony 2.0.8 and I'm using 2.6. Till now i had no major problem with this book and had reworked half of this book. (its non-english book)

Comment: You could learn the basics with this version but you will have some other troubles with a 3 years outdated book :)

Comment: Note that this version is no longer support since september 2013. http://symfony.com/roadmap?version=2.0#checker